# blazor server app .net6 razor component using component tag not rendered

Tags: .net, razor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I know there are several posts regarding similar problems but none of them provides a solution for me. I created a new Blazor server-app using .net6 and made a few modifications to use a razor component. This is the folder/file structure of my project:

[image]

The file CounterComponent.razor looks as follows:

```
<PageTitle>CounterComponent</PageTitle>

<h1>CounterComponent</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

The file Counter.razor contains

```
@page "/counter"
@namespace RazorComponents.Pages
@using RazorComponents.Pages.Shared

<component type="typeof(CounterComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

but the `<component>` tag is not rendered. If I add the `<component>` tag to _Layouts.cshtml it is rendered. I actually try to follow the instructions made [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for rendering dynamic components is

```
<DynamicComponent Type="typeof(CounterComponent)" Parameters="@parameters"/>
```

And you can define parameters for dynamic components like this

```
@code {   
    private IDictionary<string, object> parameters = ...;
}
```

Comment: Replacing
<component type="typeof(CounterComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /> by <DynamicComponent Type="typeof(CounterComponent)"> leads to the following error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Type'. The error seems to be connected to <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /> in _Host.cshtml

Comment: Your counter component does not have parameters so use this instead  <DynamicComponent Type="typeof(CounterComponent)" />

Comment: I already do this.

Comment: Yes, I see, and just tried solution at my side and all is fine, are you sure this line of code is generating error    <DynamicComponent Type="typeof(CounterComponent)" />

Comment: It is the only thing I have changed. If I remove this line, the error is gone.